# Show only credit card option with Paypal in iOS And Android

Tags: paypal

Want to display only credit card option in payment screen of paypal. how i can hide log in with paypal option in UI of iOS and android.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to hide the pay with PayPal option with Standard and Express Checkout. You would need to sign up for Direct Credit Card processing to only process cards.